# Write csv file from QT. It worked on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, csv

I'm writing a program that requires to write csv from QT. The codes are as below:

```
void MainWindow::writeUserData(){
CSVWriter writerHeader;
writerHeader.setSeparator(";");
writerHeader.openFile(m_path+"users/header.csv");

QString fileName = m_path + "users/"+ m_userData["userId"] + "_" + m_userData["name"] + "_" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString()+".csv";

if(!Experiment::MAC_COMP){
    fileName = fileName.replace(" ","_");
    fileName = fileName.replace(":","_");
    fileName[1] =':';
}

CSVWriter writerUserData;
writerUserData.setSeparator(";");
writerUserData.openFile(fileName);

QStringList header;
QStringList d;
QMapIterator<QString,QString> i(m_userData);
while(i.hasNext()){
    i.next();
    header<< i.key();
    d<<i.value();
}

writerHeader.setColumnNames(header, true);
writerUserData.setColumnNames(header);
writerUserData.write(d,true);

writerHeader.closeFile();
writerUserData.closeFile();
}
```

It worked perfectly fine on Mac but failed to write the file on Windows. Does anybody know why? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No debugger? Try harder.

Comment: Nothing particularly obvious or odious in the code provided. Fire up the debugger and make sure the assembled file path makes sense on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. I did try debugging. Because I need to log data later on in this file, debugging only told me that "impossible to open the file" and "impossible to write in the file because m_Columns.empty() || m_File==NULL return false" which make sense because the file is not created. If you have experience please share it with me. Thanks

Comment: Just want to add that the program works on Windows, the path should be ok because I also loaded other xml files. Only the csv writer didn't work but don't know why...

Comment: Since we can't see what `m_path` contains or what `fileName` contains once you've done all the substitutions and such all we can do is guess.  I'd guess the filename is bad.

Comment: Does m_path has a trailing slash? If it is absolute or relative? Print out what path you are trying to open and check manually if it exists.

Comment: m_path is "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/ExpeMenu/" and folder "users" exists. As I said before that there are other xml files that use the same path are working but can't write this csv file because it failed to create.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in the encoding of the csv file. Especially in the line end character. I had the same problem in the past when using Qt4.x. The problem was in the `QTextStream` the `readline()` it read whole file and app crashed.